# Trying to get Linux VM information

Tags: linux, powershell, virtual-machine, powercli

Firstly, I'm currently a trainee, I may not be able to give more details or may say wrong things.
Here we have a lot of Virtual Machine, sometimes my co-workers need to make a CSV with how much data is used or free by each VMs.
They asked me to make something to:
1) Get all data from each VM
2)Make a script to 'build' a dynamic CSV with data.

The second part is already done, but the first part is actually a problem because VM can be running on Windows or Unix OS.
Someone before me had made a script using:

```
Get-WmiObject -class win32_volume -Computername $VMname|Where{$_.DriveType -eq 3}
```

Which is on a loop for each $VM.But it only gets informations on VM running Windows. After looking for sometimes I found that maybe:

```
Get-CimInstance -classname CIM_StorageVolume -Compturename $VMname|Where{$_.DriveType -eq 3}
```

Should be running. But when I run this on PowerCLI I have this error:

```
The WS-Management service cannot process the request. A DMTF resource URI was used to access a non-DMTF class.Try using a non-DMTF
```

It seems I need to use cim-session, but can't figure why and how. As for some obscure reason I can't access server and make test by myself, I would know if cim-instance could actually get what I want, and how should I use cim-sessions in a loop to make this work.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: WMI will not work on linux, and CIM is unlikely to be available by default. It may be possible to install a CIM server in your linux VMs but it's probably not necessary. There are multiple tools already available for gathering this sort of information but some will require either a client on the VM or access via SSH or similar. You could also use SNMP if your hosts have a running SNMP server

Comment: What VM software are you using? If it's Hyper-V or VMWare, there are already built-in PowerShell cmdlets for getting this information from the host.

Comment: @Al-Muhandis It seems they are using VMware v-sphere. I know there are certainly cmdlets to do this, but as I can't access by myself the server where v-sphere is host, I can't try without asking someone to run the script for me.
Since I ask this, I have found many source where:

`code`$VM.Guest.Disk

Should be able to help me get this information. But I have actually no means to know if this is right or not.

Comment: @naiimco IMO you should explain that you **need** access to the vCenter Server. You don't have to run the script on it directly - you just need an account with access and then run `Connect-VIServer servername -User username -Password pwd`. Once you're connected you can use `$vm = Get-VM ...` to get the VMs on the hosts and from there, things like `$vm.Guest.Disk`

Comment: @Al-Muhandis Yes, that's what I tried to say, but as I am not really fluent in english... In fact I succeeded Friday (someone gave me his account) by using `Connect-VIServer` then `get-VM` and then `get-VM`.
As I have not my script here, I will post an answer with my script and the output tomorrow. Thanks for your help!